# How to decide the scope of transitive dependencies introduced by different dependencies?

Tags: maven

Suppose my maven module M has the following dependencies:

```
M -> A(test scope) -> C(compile scope)
M -> B(compile scope) -> C(compile scope)
```

M depends on A and B with test and compile scope respectively. Both A and B depends on C with compile scope.
So my question is how maven decides the scope of C for M?

Comment: Transitive scope resolution is explained in https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html, so the first line would lead to a test dependency, the second one to a compile dependency. I guess that there is an order and compile wins over test, but I am not sure.

Comment: @JFMeier thanks for the input. I also thought compile scope should take precedence. But that's not the case in one of my project. So I wonder if there're certain rules that maven follows.

Comment: I would also be possible that this just decided by order. Maven has a rule to resolve dependency versions if several different exists (by depth, then by order), maybe this rule is also applied to scopes.

Comment: You can try `mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose` to see if the test scoped dep is closer (less deep) in the tree. But I would also expect the compile scope to take precedence. Also make sure that you have the latest maven version and maven-dependency-plugin version, as there have been bug fixes in this area.

Comment: Thanks for your comments :) It turned out the issue with my project is that B is a shaded jar, and C is therefore removed from its pom. I think that's why I got a test scope of C for M.